# NODE_PATH=./src wont work in .env, can't import components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. I just started learning React today and I'm trying to import components from my components folder into my app.js file with `import Todos from './components/Todos';` and I am just consistently thrown an error that says "Module not found:" I've tried setting the environment variable with NODE_PATH=./src in the .env located in the root of my directory and it still doesn't work. I also tried including NODE_PATH=src/  json package and when I run npm start I am just thrown an error that says NODE_PATH=src/ is no recognized. How do I fix this? I haven't even started learning react yet because of this headache. Using create-react-app
I also have a .env file create in the root directory with REACT_APP_NODE_PATH=./src 
but still nothing

```
src
  components
    Todos.js
App.css
App.js
index.css
index.js
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Todos.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';


class Todos extends React.Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        Todos 
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
  }
}

export default Todos;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Todos from './components/Todos';
import './App.css';


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        <Todos />
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: There is missing information, show your folder tree, show how your app defined (`package.json`), which boilerplate are you using (create-react-app)? `NODE_PATH` has nothing to do with this, the only thing may do is if you want to make absolute import and its with `jsconfig.json`

Comment: You may not be exporting the component also

Comment: @DennisVash edited, sorry

Comment: Try showing the todo component and the component which you import it

Comment: @DennisVash, sorry I just edited that in as well

Comment: I added a jsconfig.json file to the root and followed the instructions from https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component#absolute-imports and I am still getting a module error